# Why ESlint doesn't ignore directories I command to

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintignore

The ESlint, running from the root of the folder does not ignore files and folders that I've mentioned in .eslintignore file:

**.eslintignore**

```
    .git
    .vscode
    node_modules
    dist
    typedoc
    __tests__/coverage
```

**.eslintrc.cjs**

```
    module.exports = {
      root: true,
      env: {
        node: true,
        es2020: true
      },
      extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
      ],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': ["off"],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["off"],
        'array-bracket-spacing': ['error', 'never'],
        '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports': ['error', {
          'prefer': 'type-imports'
        }]
        // new rules goes here
      }
    }
```

**I run**

`eslint . -c .eslintrc.cjs --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx --max-warnings 0`

**Output**

```
    typedocs/assets/main.js:2:2271
      ✖  2:2271   Unexpected aliasing of this to local variable.  @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
      ✖  2:2288   Unexpected aliasing of this to local variable.  @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
      ✖  2:3495   Unnecessary escape character: \-.               no-useless-escape
      ✖  3:4165   E is already defined.                           no-redeclare
      ✖  3:4312   E is already defined.                           no-redeclare
      ✖  3:4361   E is already defined.                           no-redeclare
    ...
      ✖  5:2943   document is not defined.                        no-undef
      ✖  5:3096   document is not defined.                        no-undef
      ✖  5:3179   window is not defined.                          no-undef

      typedocs/assets/navigation.js:1:1
      ✖  1:1      window is not defined.                          no-undef

      typedocs/assets/search.js:1:1
      ✖  1:1      window is not defined.                          no-undef

      102 errors
```

**I TRIED**

- if delete these folders (dist/ and typedoc/) then there are no problems
- there is NO .eslintcache file, no cache (everything is clean)
- using glob patterns for .eslintignore like `typedoc/**` does not work
- these folders are also in .gitignore file ...

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR**

I want ESlint to ignore folders and files I've mentioned. I dont want to delete these folders each time I call eslint script...

Any help and piece of advice are welcome!

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the folders with slash ?

Comment: I've just tried `/dist` and `/typedoc` in the .eslintignore file - does not work =(